# Antd table cell render charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, react-table

I'm using antd to create a table which contains chart in cell, just like this [html table + chart.js](http://www.java2s.com/example/javascript/chart.js/creating-charts-in-each-row-in-an-html-table-with-chartjs.html)

I tried some tutorials of [antd table](https://ant.design/components/table/) but failed, here's my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-filter-panel-antd4167-forked-8cy3z?file=/index.js).

Is there any way or other toolbox to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add couple of packages to achieve the same  ( [Finished Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-filter-panel-antd-table-col-chart-vyhm7))

```js
"chart.js": "3.4.1",
"react-chartjs-2": "3.0.3",
```

And then Define the component and use it in the renderer

```js
{
  title: "Charts",
  render: (chartData) => {
    const data = {
      labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
      datasets: [{
        label: "# of Votes",
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)"
      }]
    };

    return <LineChart data = {
      data
    }
    />;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of chart library to display the chart. Ant Design doesn't provide charts. The famous one for react is https://recharts.org/en-US which internally uses react and d3.

I copied your code from the sandbox and added Bar chart rendering code. This is how your code should look like:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table, Input, Button, Space } from "antd";
import Highlighter from "react-highlight-words";
import { SearchOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

import {
  BarChart, Bar, Cell, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend,
} from 'recharts';

const data1 = [
  {
    name: 'Page A', uv: 4000, pv: 2400, amt: 2400,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page B', uv: 3000, pv: 1398, amt: 2210,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page C', uv: 2000, pv: 9800, amt: 2290,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page D', uv: 2780, pv: 3908, amt: 2000,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page E', uv: 1890, pv: 4800, amt: 2181,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page F', uv: 2390, pv: 3800, amt: 2500,
  },
  {
    name: 'Page G', uv: 3490, pv: 4300, amt: 2100,
  },
];

class Example extends PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
      <BarChart
        width={500}
        height={300}
        data={data1}
        margin={{
          top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5,
        }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="name" />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        <Bar dataKey="pv" fill="#8884d8" />
        <Bar dataKey="uv" fill="#82ca9d" />
      </BarChart>
    );
  }
}

const data = [
  {
    key: "1",
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "2",
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "3",
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park"
  },
  {
    key: "4",
    name: "Jim Red",
    age: 32,
    address: "London No. 2 Lake Park"
  }
];

const chartData = [
  { year: "1991", value: 3 },
  { year: "1992", value: 4 },
  { year: "1993", value: 3.5 },
  { year: "1994", value: 5 },
  { year: "1995", value: 4.9 },
  { year: "1996", value: 6 },
  { year: "1997", value: 7 },
  { year: "1998", value: 9 },
  { year: "1999", value: 13 }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchText: "",
    searchedColumn: ""
  };

  getColumnSearchProps = (dataIndex) => ({
    filterDropdown: ({
      setSelectedKeys,
      selectedKeys,
      confirm,
      clearFilters
    }) => (
      <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
        <Input
          ref={(node) => {
            this.searchInput = node;
          }}
          placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
          value={selectedKeys[0]}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])
          }
          onPressEnter={() =>
            this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)
          }
          style={{ marginBottom: 8, display: "block" }}
        />
        <Space>
          <Button
            type="primary"
            onClick={() => this.handleSearch(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
            icon={<SearchOutlined />}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Search
          </Button>
          <Button
            onClick={() => this.handleReset(clearFilters)}
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 90 }}
          >
            Reset
          </Button>
          <Button
            type="link"
            size="small"
            onClick={() => {
              confirm({ closeDropdown: false });
              this.setState({
                searchText: selectedKeys[0],
                searchedColumn: dataIndex
              });
            }}
          >
            Filter
          </Button>
        </Space>
      </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: (filtered) => (
      <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? "#1890ff" : undefined }} />
    ),
    onFilter: (value, record) =>
      record[dataIndex]
        ? record[dataIndex]
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(value.toLowerCase())
        : "",
    onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: (visible) => {
      if (visible) {
        setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select(), 100);
      }
    },
    render: (text) =>
      this.state.searchedColumn === dataIndex ? (
        <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#ffc069", padding: 0 }}
          searchWords={[this.state.searchText]}
          autoEscape
          textToHighlight={text ? text.toString() : ""}
        />
      ) : (
        text
      )
  });

  handleSearch = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
    confirm();
    this.setState({
      searchText: selectedKeys[0],
      searchedColumn: dataIndex
    });
  };

  handleReset = (clearFilters) => {
    clearFilters();
    this.setState({ searchText: "" });
  };

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        title: "Name",
        dataIndex: "name",
        key: "name",
        width: "30%",
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps("name")
      },
      {
        title: "Age",
        dataIndex: "age",
        key: "age",
        width: "20%",
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps("age")
      },
      {
        title: "Address",
        dataIndex: "address",
        key: "address",
        ...this.getColumnSearchProps("address"),
        sorter: (a, b) => a.address.length - b.address.length,
        sortDirections: ["descend", "ascend"]
      },
      {
        title: "Charts",
        render: () => (
          <>
           <Example />
          </>
        )
      }
    ];
    return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

I have used recharts library for Charts.

Here is the Github link for your example: https://github.com/siddharth-sunchu/antd-chart-example